# Using i18n in HTML / JSON

Tags: javascript, html, i18next

I am trying to use i18n in HTML and JS files, I have it all added in a js file which is part of my HTML page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  i18next
    .use(window.i18nextXHRBackend)
    .init(
      {
        backend: {
          loadPath: '../i18n/en.json'
        }
      },
      function(err, t) {
        jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $);
        messagesLoaded = true;
      }
    );
});
```

Further down I have:

```
createButton.textContent = i18next.t('character.create');
cancelButton.textContent = i18next.t('general.exit');
```

However, when I go and load the page, it shows `character.create`, instead of `Create Character`

I have my en.json file one directory above in an i18n directory and the en.json contains this:

```
{
"general": {
    "password": "Password",
    "access": "Access",
    "add": "Add",
    "drop": "Drop",
    "accept": "Accept",
    "cancel": "Cancel",
    "exit": "Exit",
    "back": "Back",
    "name": "Name",
    "purchase": "Purchase",
    "type-one": "Type 1",
    "type": "Type {{value}}",
    "consume": "Consume",
    "open": "Open",
    "equip": "Equip",
    "confiscate": "Confiscate",
    "withdraw": "Withdraw",
    "store": "Store",
    "unit-price": "Unit price: ",
    "price": "Price: ",
    "amount": "Amount: ",
    "inventory": "Inventory"
},
"login": {
    "message": "Welcome back to LS-V. You need to insert your password below in order to log in",
    "error": "Your password is incorrect. Please try again."
},
"character": {
    "title": "Character list",
    "create": "Create new",
    "surname": "Surname",
    "age": "Age: ",
}
```

Would anyone know any reason for why this is happening? It's happening across every page that I try to use i18n, including in HTML pages. I'm trying to figure out what I am doing wrong but getting stuck on this now.

Comment: take out the quotes `textContent = i18next.t(character.create);`

Comment: I don't think that would fix the issue, I swear I had this working ages ago. Here is a section of HTML code and it doesn't have quotes.

    `<button class="error-hide" data-i18n="general.accept" onclick="hideError();"></button>`